# Program to work row by row instead of entire range?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a macro that goes through 2 columns (B&C) & highlights individual part numbers that are different between merged cells. That part is working just fine. Where I am stuck, however, is getting it to work row-by-row rather than comparing the entire ranges in B & C. I've looked around the places I usually find solutions but I have found nothing that works for what I am trying to do so far, or at least nothing that I can make work.  It seems that no matter what I try if it finds a part number in both columns - regardless of whether that number is in the cell I want to compare or in a completely different one - it returns a match.

Below is the code that highlights differences in column C. It would be really excellent to modify it  to go row by row & highlight differences in both columns at the same time (presently I have a macro for each column). It'd be even more excellent to not only (for example) highlight the mismatches in B2 & C2, but also display those non-matching values from B2 in D2 & from C2 in E2, but that is just an idea I have, not sure if it is possible. Can someone help with this problem?

```
Sub BOMMAGIC_2NDCOLUMN()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rng2HL As Range, rngCheck As Range, dictWords As Object
    Dim a() As Variant, b() As Variant, wordlist As Variant, wordStart As Long
    Set r = Selection
     'Change the addresses below to match your data.
    Set rng2HL = Range("C2:C824")
    Set rngCheck = Range("B2:B824")
    a = rng2HL.Value
    b = rngCheck.Value
    Set dictWords = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     'Load unique words from second column into a dictionary for easy checking
    For i = LBound(b, 1) To UBound(b, 1)
        wordlist = Split(b(i, 1), " ")
        For j = LBound(wordlist) To UBound(wordlist)
            If Not dictWords.Exists(wordlist(j)) Then
                dictWords.Add wordlist(j), wordlist(j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
     'Reset range to highlight to all black font.
    rng2HL.Font.ColorIndex = 1
     'Check words one by one against dictionary.
    For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
        wordlist = Split(a(i, 1), " ")
        For j = LBound(wordlist) To UBound(wordlist)
            If Not dictWords.Exists(wordlist(j)) Then
                wordStart = InStr(a(i, 1), wordlist(j))
                 'Change font color of word to red.
                rng2HL.Cells(i).Characters(wordStart, Len(wordlist(j))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to iterate your range, via cells, so for each cell in rng2HL.cells or for each row in rng2HL.Rows.

Comment: I sort of follow what you're saying but what I am changing isn't working..from your comments I need to change the below code:

    Set rng2HL = Range("C2:C824")
    Set rngCheck = Range("B2:B824")
    a = rng2HL.Value
    b = rngCheck.Value

But my edits have not yet worked.  Could you possibly provide further info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
Sub BOMMAGIC_2NDCOLUMN_Test()

    Dim rw As Range, v1, v2, arrB, arrC, v

    For Each rw In Range("B2:C824").Rows

        rw.Font.Color = vbBlack
        rw.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
        v1 = Trim(rw.Cells(1).Value)
        v2 = Trim(rw.Cells(2).Value)

        If Len(v1) > 0 And Len(v2) > 0 Then
            arrB = Uniques(Split(v1, " "))
            arrC = Uniques(Split(v2, " "))

            BlankAllMatches arrB, arrC 'remove all matches

            For Each v In arrB
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    HighlightText rw.Cells(1), CStr(v), vbRed
                    rw.Cells(1).Offset(0, 2) = rw.Cells(1).Offset(0, 2) & " " & v
                End If
            Next v
            For Each v In arrC
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    HighlightText rw.Cells(2), CStr(v), vbBlue
                    rw.Cells(2).Offset(0, 2) = rw.Cells(2).Offset(0, 2) & " " & v
                End If
            Next v

        End If

    Next rw
End Sub

'Set any elements common to both arrays to ""
' Note: arrays should not contain duplicate values
Sub BlankAllMatches(ByRef a, ByRef b)
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        For x = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
            If a(i) <> "" And a(i) = b(x) Then
                a(i) = ""
                b(x) = ""
            End If
       Next x
    Next i
End Sub

'EDIT: highlight all instances of "txt"
Sub HighlightText(rng As Range, txt As String, clr As Long)
    Dim wordStart, pos As Long
    pos = InStr(1, rng.Value, txt)
    Do While pos > 0
        rng.Characters(pos, Len(txt)).Font.Color = clr
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, rng.Value, txt)
    Loop
End Sub

'EDIT: added to deal with duplicates...
'return an array of unique values from input array
Function Uniques(arr)
    Dim v
    Static dict As Object
    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.RemoveAll
    For Each v In arr
        dict(v) = True
    Next v
    Uniques = dict.keys
End Function
```

Comment: One final question - it looks like it does not catch duplicates within the same cell.  I do not have many instances of this so it's tough to spot, but if I have one part number repeated 2x in one bill of material's cell the macro is only changing the text color of one.  If it's not possible to catch duplicates I still thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks sir!

Comment: FYI there is a bug in this code - i had not anticipated duplicate values within each cell. Revising and will post corrected version...

Comment: Thanks again Tim - I am really grateful for your help!  This works perfectly!